# Use webassembly or no?

Tags: webassembly

I want to know if is it good in this moment to begin to use wasm to create 2D game using code C and Javascript and convert it to wasm.

Because I see in the internet that webassembly is new and isn't compatible with all navigators.

Comment: Recommendations are explicitly off topic here.

Comment: Unity is coming to WASM.

Comment: Reject obfuscated close-source software. Just say no to WAsm. Also - off-topic.

Comment: @einpoklum where is Wasm more obfuscated then compiled and compressed Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you like it, go ahead. Just redirect/iframe to [browsehappy.com](https://browsehappy.com/) if the User is outdated.